# Most general form of the velocity correlation tensor

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, velocity, correlation-functions, turbulence

The most general form of velocity correlation tensor for homogeneous and isotropic turbulence is given by:

$R_{ij}(r)=A(r)r_{i}r_{j}+B(r)\delta_{ij}$

How can this depend on $r_{i}r_{j}$ if it is isotropic? How to derive this relation (what are the logical steps)?